# How to write test cases to cover both if and else condition

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have the following code in my constructor method in apex class.

```
public Page4Controller() {

    User currentUser = [SELECT contactId  FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
    System.debug('Current user' + currentUser);
    //Fetch the current contact object
    if(String.isNotBlank(currentUser.ContactId)) {

        contact  = [
            SELECT  AccountId, firstName, lastName, MiddleName,  Nickname__c, Suffix, MailingStreet, MailingCity,
                    MailingStateCode, Certify_Complete_and_Correct__c,  Certify_Download_Instructions_to_PreCan__c
            FROM Contact
            WHERE Id = :currentUser.ContactId
            LIMIT 1
        ];

        System.debug('contact information: ' + contact );

        //Fetch the current application object  
        application = [          
            SELECT Id, Contact__c, Attend_College_after_High_School__c
            FROM Application__c 
            WHERE Contact__c =: currentUser.contactId
            LIMIT 1];                     
    }
}
```

And the following submit method in the apex class

```
public pagereference submit() {  
    if (
        contact.Certify_Complete_and_Correct__c == false ||
        contact.Certify_Download_Instructions_to_PreCan__c == false

    )
    {
        ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Please make sure all required fields are populated.');
        ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
        return null;
    }

    // ALO Code   
    if(application.Attend_College_after_High_School__c == 'No')    
    {    
        acc = [              
            SELECT Id, OwnerId
            FROM Account
            WHERE Id =: contact.AccountId
        ];

        contact.ALO__c = acc.OwnerId;                  
    }        
    else if(application.Attend_College_after_High_School__c == 'Yes')  
    {                        
        ziptoLOD = [          
            SELECT Id, Name, LOD__c
            FROM Zip_3_to_LOD__c
            WHERE Name =: contact.Extract_Zipcode__c

        ];

        contact.ALO__c = ziptoLOD.LOD__c;          
    }
```

I don't know how to write test cases for the above conditions so that it covers both the if and else code.

Here is the test class I am working on

```
@isTest public with sharing class Page4ControllerTest {
    static testMethod void submit_Test() {

        Profile AdminProfile = [select id from profile where name='System Administrator']; 
        UserRole AdminRole = [SELECT id from UserRole where name = 'Admin'];

        User currentuser = new User();
        currentuser.firstname      ='James';
        currentuser.lastname      ='Dobb';
        currentuser.email         ='abcdefg@gmail.com';
        currentuser.username      ='abcdefg@gmail.com';
        currentuser.alias        ='jdobb';
        currentuser.TimeZoneSidKey  ='GMT';
        currentuser.LocaleSidKey    ='en_US';
        currentuser.emailencodingkey  ='UTF-8';
        currentuser.languagelocalekey  ='en_US';
        currentuser.ProfileId     = AdminProfile.Id;
        currentuser.userroleid     = AdminRole.Id;
        insert currentuser;

        Account acc= new Account();
        acc.OwnerId='005r0000001i9xA';
        acc.Name='Atlanta Area Tech School';
        acc.RecordTypeId='012r00000005DsA';

        Zip_3_to_LOD__c zip= new Zip_3_to_LOD__c();
        zip.Name = '480';
        zip.LOD__c = '005t0000001LDpi';

        Contact contact   = new Contact(); 
        contact.firstName = 'Alex';
        contact.lastName  = 'Cauller';
        contact.email     = 'alexcauller@gmail.com';
        contact.AccountId = acc.Id;

        system.runas(currentuser){
            insert acc;
            insert contact;
            insert zip;
        }

        Application__c app= new Application__c();
        app.Contact__c = contact.Id;
        app.Attend_College_after_High_School__c= 'No';

        system.runas(currentuser){
            insert app;
        }

        Profile pr = [select id from profile where name='......']; 
        User u = new User();
        u.firstname      ='James';
        u.lastname      ='Dobb';
        u.email         ='xyz@gmail.com';
        u.username      ='xyz@gmail.com';
        u.alias        ='jdobb';
        u.TimeZoneSidKey  ='GMT';
        u.LocaleSidKey    ='en_US';
        u.emailencodingkey  ='UTF-8';
        u.languagelocalekey  ='en_US';
        u.ProfileId     = pr.Id;
        u.contactId      =contact.id;
        insert u;

        system.runAs(u){
            System.Test.startTest();
            Page4Controller controllerClass = new Page4Controller();
            controllerClass.contact.Certify_Complete_and_Correct__c = false;
            controllerClass.contact.Certify_Download_Instructions_to_PreCan__c = false;
            controllerClass.submit();
            System.AssertEquals(controllerClass.contact.ALO__c,acc.OwnerId);
            controllerClass.application.Attend_College_after_High_School__c = 'Yes';
            controllerClass.submit();
            System.AssertEquals(controllerClass.contact.ALO__c,zip.LOD__c);
            controllerClass.previouspage();
            System.Test.stopTest();
        }
    }
}

    When I run the test case, the test case fails and generates the following error on both the assert statements
```

> System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: null, Actual: 005r0000001i9xAAAQ

Comment: Avoid using hard coded Id's and add the full code snippet for better understanding of your code

Comment: @RCS The one with the  hardcoded Id's( Account and zip 3 to LOD) are the records that already exist in Salesforce. My code just traverse through them and find the required information. How do I add that information in my test class? Also I have updated the code above a little bit. Let me know what part of code you still find missing?

Comment: Using @seeAllData in test class is not a good practice instead try to create you test data in the test class itself so you don't need to use the org's data while running test class

Comment: I am a beginner in testing. Can you provide me the code snippet so that I could get some starting point? I am stuck right now.

Comment: Please go through the trailhead

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments here, it looks like you are on the right path here.

The next logical leap I think you should take is that *you can have more than one test method in your test class*.

In fact, having more than one test method is good practice. Doing so allows you to make your unit tests more <strike>specific (which means if something goes wrong, or a test fails, it'll be easier to determine what the issue actually is).</strike>

**+edit:**
While "specific" is a word that can be used here (compared to your existing test, which attempts to test *everything*, breaking out into more tests does make each test more specific), as Adrian points out, the better point to focus on is that splitting into many test methods makes each test more *atomic*.

If you're new to the term, "atmoic" is used to mean a fundamental, indivisible operation (despite the fact that real, physical atoms are indeed made of more fundamental parts).

Atomic tests are easier to set up. You're aiming to exercise only one fundamental aspect of your code at a time, so you only need a small and specific set of test data to guarantee your target code is executed.

Atomic tests also help identify what might be wrong with your code simply by the fact that one test in particular failed. If I have a controller with multiple methods, and my `testSaveUpdatesFieldX()` method is failing but nothing else is, then I know that something isn't right with "fieldX" in my `save()` method without needing to look at any code. That's as much from atomic tests as it is from having a useful naming convention (and sticking to it).

**/edit**

In this particular case, I would have no fewer than 3 test methods:

- One to test what happens when `Certify_Complete_and_Correct__c` is false (by the way, testing booleans for equality isn't required. `MyBool == true` can be replaced with, simply, `MyBool`. `MyBool == false` can be replaced with `!MyBool`)
- One to test what happens when the application has `Attend_College_after_High_School__c` set to "No"
- One to test what happens when the application has `Attend_College_after_High_School__c` set to "Yes"

Again, the point here is to make each test as short and focused as possible. Each of those tests is meant to cover one distinct situation (and path through your code)

This is known as **branch coverage** (each possible branch that your code can take has been tested). It's not always feasible to attain branch coverage, but the code that you've shared is simple enough that it should be easy to accomplish.

One of the other things that Salesforce recommends for unit testing is to put your test setup into a single method using the `@testSetup` annotation. Not only does that keep all of your setup in a single place (following the DRY principle, which stands for "Don't Repeat Yourself"), but it's supposed to help your tests execute faster as well (a good thing once you start to have several hundred to several thousand test methods in your entire org).

To help get you started, here's an example of how I would rewrite part of your test class:

```
@isTest 
public with sharing class Page4ControllerTest {

    // Test setup method (best practice)
    // This is automatically executed by Salesforce
    // It'll count towards your governor limits for each test, but has the
    //   benefit that Salesforce will automatically restore your test data
    //   to this exact state after each testmethod is executed
    @testSetup
    static void makeData(){
        Profile AdminProfile = [select id from profile where name='System Administrator']; 
        UserRole AdminRole = [SELECT id from UserRole where name = 'Admin'];

        // You can set fields for an SObject in the constructor.
        // This is equivalent to what you had before, but executes a bit faster
        //   (and perhaps more importantly, requires less typing)
        User currentuser = new User(
            firstName = 'James',
            lastName = 'Dobb',
            email ='abcdefg@gmail.com',
            username ='abcdefg@gmail.com',
            alias ='jdobb',
            TimeZoneSidKey ='GMT',
            LocaleSidKey ='en_US',
            emailencodingkey ='UTF-8',
            languagelocalekey ='en_US',
            ProfileId = AdminProfile.Id,
            userroleid = AdminRole.Id
        );

        insert currentuser;

        // Hard-coding Ids like this is generally a bad idea
        // I'd prefer using the user that you created and inserted just before here
        Account acc= new Account(
            OwnerId = '005r0000001i9xA',
            Name = 'Atlanta Area Tech School',
            RecordTypeId = '012r00000005DsA'
        );

        Zip_3_to_LOD__c zip= new Zip_3_to_LOD__c(
            Name = '480',
            LOD__c = '005t0000001LDpi'
        );

        Contact contact   = new Contact(
            firstName = 'Alex',
            lastName = 'Cauller',
            email = 'alexcauller@gmail.com',
            AccountId = acc.Id
        );

        system.runas(currentuser){
            insert acc;
            insert contact;
            insert zip;
        }

        Application__c app= new Application__c(
            Contact__c = contact.Id,
            Attend_College_after_High_School__c= 'No'
        );

        system.runas(currentuser){
            insert app;
        }
    }

    // Using the @testMethod annotation does the same thing as using the keyword
    //   in your method signature.
    // The benefit with this approach is that if you need to prevent a test 
    //   from running (for some reason), you only need to comment out the annotation
    //   (as opposed to the entire method. Again, less typing)
    @testMethod
    static void submitGeneratePageMessage() {
        // Any test-specific setup can be done in the test method itself
        Profile pr = [select id from profile where name='......']; 

        // One of the downsides of using the @testSetup method is that you need to 
        //   query for your test data in each test method.
        // Salesforce claims that it's still faster to query repeatedly than it is to
        //   create/insert over and over
        Contact contact = [SELECT Id FROM Contact LIMIT 1];

        User u = new User(
            firstname ='James',
            lastname ='Dobb',
            email ='xyz@gmail.com',
            username ='xyz@gmail.com',
            alias ='jdobb',
            TimeZoneSidKey ='GMT',
            LocaleSidKey ='en_US',
            emailencodingkey ='UTF-8',
            languagelocalekey ='en_US',
            ProfileId = pr.Id,
            contactId = contact.id
        );

        insert u;

        // Some assertions need to be run before running the actual "test"
        //   of this test method.
        // This one is optional, but including it gives you a stronger argument
        //   as to the correctness of your code
        System.assertEquals(false, ApexPages.hasMessages(), "Expected that there would be no page messages before running the test");

        system.runAs(u){
            // This part is still "test setup" in my eyes, so I generally
            //   keep it outside of "test.startTest()"/"test.stopTest()"
            Page4Controller controllerClass = new Page4Controller();
            controllerClass.contact.Certify_Complete_and_Correct__c = false;

            // You can set both of your target fields to false, but if we want
            //   to exercise the "OR" part of your if statement, we should only
            //   set one
            //controllerClass.contact.Certify_Download_Instructions_to_PreCan__c = false;

            // Now, we get to the test proper.
            // Personal preference, I use starttest/stoptest around as little
            //   code as I can.
            // This is helpful if you ever need to make assertions against
            //   how many queries/cpu/dml/etc... that your code consumes
            Test.startTest();
            controllerClass.submit();
            Test.stopTest();
        }

        // I like to keep my assertions separate from everything else
        // Since this code path adds a page message, that's what we should assert
        // The third parameter of assertEquals() and assertNotEquals() is optional, but
        //   very helpful.
        // It gives you the ability to set the message that you'll see when the
        //   assertion fails.
        // Being specific here helps track down which test is failing, and 
        //   may even give you an idea as to what's wrong in the code being tested.
        System.assertEquals(true, ApexPages.hasMessages(), "Expected that there would be a page message after running the test");
    }
}
```

I hope that you can take it from here, and implement the other two test methods.

Comment: Rather than more *specific* I might say the advantage is the tests are more *atomic*, a useful concept when testing units of code.

Comment: @AdrianLarson good point, I'll edit to reflect that.